# error when attempting to test whether the service worker has activated or not with querySelector

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm new to service worker and somewhat web development and this is the problem I'm having:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title> First service worker</title>

<h1> Service worker testing </h1>
<output> </output>

<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("serviceworker.js", {
            scope: "/"
        })
            .then(registration => {
                document.querySelecctor("output").innerHTML = "Service worker is registered SUCCESFULLY";
            })
            .catch(error => {
                document.querySelector("output").innerHTML = error;
            })
    } else {
        document.querySelector("output").innerHTML = "Service worker is NOT supported!";
    }
</script>
```

The above is my code for checking if service worker is registered and this is what I got online. Please help me to figure this out thank you guys!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXRii.png)

Even though it said that querySelector is not a function but it works normal as I used that method on other of my tests, so I am confusing at the moment